# Как поместить конструктор выше исходного кода в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Visual Studio с определенного момента стала отображать конструтор ASP.Net WebForms снизу. Как сделать так, чтобы он отображался сверху?

Comment: Попробуй на кнопку разделить нажать

Comment: @Alex78191 таки уже, проблема в том, что конструктор "разделился" вниз, а код вверх. И это бьёт мне по глазу

Comment: Попробуй окна кода и конструктора поперетаскивать.